# How to create a scrollable 2d object

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am building a simulation and have a map that i want displayed and to be able to be scrollable however every approach I have tried (ScrollPane, JScrollPane, Component) has failed.  Either the scroll bars show up and do not function or do not show up at all.  I have googled this to death and have not find a viable solution, does any know how to make a java 2d object scrollable?  Thank you in advance!

Thanks guys figured it out, as it was a stupid mistake! lol

Comment: You're doing something wrong, but what, we can't say, and we're certainly not going to try to write you a tutorial since better ones are already out there. Consider creating and posting a small compilable and runnable example program that shows your attempt to solve this, and we'll be able to better see what you're doing wrong and advise you on how to fix it. Luck.

Comment: It could be nothing more than your not adding your component to the JScrollPane's viewport, or that the component being scrolled is not larger than the viewport, but again, without code, who knows?

Comment: Your right i had to set the components size and as soon as i did that it worked, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

The Swing tutorial has explanations and examples : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable

Your component must implement the `Scrollable` interface.